# RISCV32 and Buildroot support

Tags: embedded-linux, riscv, buildroot

So we are trying to make our own Linux capable RISCV 32-bit processor.
**Does Buildroot support RISCV 32bit?**
**If so, what are the minimal requirements and extensions that are required by Buildroot?**

Answer (score 0):

yes buildroot support riscv32.
Take a look at
https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/arch/Config.in.riscv and https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/arch/arch.mk.riscv.

For requirement take a look at https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/support/config-fragments/autobuild/br-riscv32.config.